# Is "amend XX" a commonly understood English term to express "add something to XX" or "modify XX"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, meaning-in-context

In our company, we've recently had a discussion about the usage of the verb *amend* in the context of a screen in our software user interface, where a button reads *amend set* (meaning *add something to this set* or *modify this set*). We're mostly non-native English speakers and this word seemed a bit exotic. Is it commonly used in this context?

From a non-native English speaker perspective, I'd prefer *modify set*. Our target audience is native (British) English speaking, though.

Comment: Are adding to the set, removing from it or both?

Comment: @Mitch: Adding, removing, even renaming the set...

Comment: OK. To Americans, 'amend' is part of 'amendment' which is a modification of a legal document (like the constitution), which usually comes as an additional document possibly denying ('repealing') things in the main document. So 'amend' sounds like 'add' to Americans, but much more formal (not exotic). Use 'add' if you're just adding, or 'change' or 'modify' (either is fine, they are both well used in computer interfaces).

Comment: @Mitch: True. *Formal* would better describe it than *exotic*. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this definition of *amend*:

> - 1 : to put right; especially : to make emendations in (as a text)
> - 2
>
>   - a : to change or modify for the better : improve
>   - b : to alter especially in phraseology; especially : to alter formally by modification, deletion, or addition

*Modify*, on the other hand, is defined like this:

> - 1 : to make less extreme : moderate
> - 2
>
>   - a : to limit or restrict the
>       meaning of especially in a grammatical construction
>   - b : to change (a
>       vowel) by umlaut
> - 3
>
>   - a : to make minor changes in
>   - b : to make basic or fundamental changes in often to give a new orientation to or to serve a new end

Also, if you search for synonyms, you will find *amend* in the list of *modify*'s synonyms, and vice versa.

From a position of non-English speaker I would say that *amend* seems to have a meaning closer to *change something to make it better*, while *modify* has a meaning closer to *change something*. If I saw *amend set* in an application, that would definitely confuse me and make me thinking "what did that developer mean?".

Comment: That was my impression, too. It seemed to me that *amend* had a semantics indicating a change of quality that goes with the modification - as opposed to the simple *modify*

Comment: +1. As a native speaker, I broadly agree with this answer. I'll add, though, that the word *amend* does not strike me as at all "exotic".

Comment: @TRiG: You're probably right. By finding it "exotic" I meant finding it "exotic" in the context of generally modifying the object...

Comment: Just for an additional perspective, as a native speaker I have never heard modify used in the manner of definition 1.

Answer (score 2):

From OED: "To free (a thing) from faults, correct (what is faulty), rectify."

Is *amend* really the right word for what you describe? It could be that somebody has got confused with *append*: "To add in writing by way of supplement or appendix."

Comment: Yes. *amend* really doesn't rectify things in the real-life context. It just modifies things...

Answer (score 2):

I received an e-mail from Pearson, where I can amend my contact preferences:

[image]

As you say, for a native (British) English speaking audience "amend" is obviously a synonym for "alter".

Answer (score 1):

'Amend' is generally used as correction as in "Amend your mistakes". You can use 'Modify' or 'Edit'.

Comment: Yes, "amend" seems fine to me (an American).